# How to store sanitized user's input in database using InsertInto

Tags: php, mysql, validation, input

I want to store some user's input variables into mysql. However, they are stored as :username and :password instead of the user's input.

```php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome", "nome", "password");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST["username"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST["password"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result); 

if($username && $password){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (':username', ':password')";    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST["password"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }else{
    print "Dati non corretti";
};
```

```html
<h1> Login Form </h1>
  <form action="?" method="post"> Name
    <input name="username"  value="" />


    Password
    <input name="password"  value=""/>

    <input type="submit" name="my_form_submit_button"
           value="Login" />

    </form>
```

When I check the phpMyAdmin table, the variables are stored as :username and :password.
I would like to store them as the user's input. For example, if the user's username input is Mark, I would like to store it as Mark, instead of :username.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you replace```':username'``` to ```:username``` and try again. The ```'``` convert it as a string argument so the bindParam should skip it.

Comment: Or you can use ```$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";``` and ```$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST["username"]);```

Comment: @Cotur in this case, the stored values are  "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally working now, save the following code as a php file and run it.

I changed the following things.

1. The INSERT sql's values `':username'` to `:username` and same to `':password'` to `:password` because the `'` single quote converts inside to string and `bindValue` can skip it.
2. Removed `?` from `<form action"?"` to `<form action""`, It's defines the request page is itself.
3. At php code, I added `if($_POST)` statement to check if any POST request exist before the instering values to database table.
4. And last change is at the `bindParam`, I added `PDO::PARAM_STR` as a last variable to send fuction to define the values type.

```
<?php


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome", "nome", "password");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);

if($_POST){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}




?>

<h1> Login Form </h1>
<form action="" method="post"> Name
<input name="username"  value="" />


Password
<input name="password"  value=""/>

<input type="submit" name="my_form_submit_button"
        value="Login" />

</form>
```

Comment: @Dharman , you are totally right. I've added the changes with explainings.

Comment: Thanks. BTW `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default value so no need to add it.

Comment: Yep, I added it cuz to show how it works. Kim can remember it when trying to add other parameter types to db.